# Lack of scale in Schrödinger equation for square-inverse potential

Tags: quantum-mechanics, schroedinger-equation, renormalization, centrifugal-force

I see that if we set our potential in schrodinger equation to be a inverse-square dependence we don't have a typical unit of length as we have for hydrogen atom.

$$-{\hbar^2\over 2m}\nabla^2\psi + {\alpha\over r^2}\psi=E\psi$$

Is clear that ${2m\over \hbar^2}\alpha$ is dimensionless.
When I treat this system as a simple system, I found some divergences and continuous spectra for bound states. I found a promiscuous relationship with the squared angular momentum eigenvalues (in units of $\hbar^2$) and the strength $\alpha$ of the potential to.
This relationship is so promiscuous that if I forget the spectra of angular momentum and derive this by behaviour of homogeneous polynomials of $(\cos(\phi)\sin(\theta);\sin(\phi)\sin(\theta);\cos(\theta))$ near to $r=0$ I have a freedom to set the eigenvalues for embrace the strength coupling or part of it.

$$L^2\psi\rightarrow [l(l+1)\hbar^2-2m\beta]\psi$$

when in this case, $\psi\rightarrow r^lY_l(\theta,\phi)$,with $Y_l(\theta,\phi)$ is a homogeneous polynomial of oder $l$, this clear means that $l$ is an integer. And $\beta$ is a arbitrarily real number. If I put $\beta=\alpha$ then the force is erased by the centrifugal force.

- This mean that we have to consider the Renormalization Group ideas?
- What is the relationship with the angular momentum and the renormalization techniques?

Comment: For the corresponding 1D problem, see e.g. [A.M. Essin and D.J. Griffiths, _Quantum mechanics of the $1/x^2$ potential,_ Am. J. Phys. 74 (2006) 109–117 (2006)](http://dx.doi.org/10.1119/1.2165248), which also discusses renormalization.

Comment: Thanks ^^ this paper is very clear and nice, but my doubt in the relationship of the angular momentum spectra with this potential is still alive.

Comment: We already know from classical mechanics that the potentials $\alpha r^{2}$ and $\alpha/r$ are special, in that they are the only central force potentials with stable closed orbits.

Comment: For $\alpha/r^2$, "inverse cube force" we have a [Cotes spirals orbits](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cotes%27s_spiral)
and [Poisont spirals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poinsot%27s_spirals) may be "closed", but in a strange way.